# How to get the eclipse project Dependency?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to write a method (in java) which prints all the project dependencies.
Is there a file which eclipse saves this project dependencies list ?
I look at the files in example eclipse project:
.  ..  .indexes  .location  .markers  org.eclipse.jdt.core
but none of them contains the relevant information.

Comment: In the project folder, look at the `.classpath` file

Answer (score 1):

It's the `.classpath` file in the root of your project folder. It might be hidden by the file system so you would need to reveal it by changing some settings of your file system.